# Implementing the square root method through successive approximation

Tags: algorithm, square-root

Determining the square root through successive approximation is implemented using the following algorithm:

1. Begin by guessing that the square root is x / 2. Call that guess g.
2. The actual square root must lie between g and x/g. At each step in the successive approximation, generate a new guess by averaging g and x/g.
3. Repeat step 2 until the values of g and x/g are as close together as the precision of the hardware allows. In Java, the best way to check for this condition is to test whether the average is equal to either of the values used to generate it.

What really confuses me is the last statement of step 3. I interpreted it as follows:

```
private double sqrt(double x) {
    double g = x / 2;
    while(true) {
        double average = (g + x/g) / 2;
        if(average == g || average == x/g) break;
        g = average;
    }

    return g;
}
```

This seems to just cause an infinite loop. I am following the algorithm exactly, if the average equals either g or x/g (the two values used to generate it) then we have our answer ?

Comment: What input are you using? It seems to terminate for me...

Comment: Terminates for me with 2.23606797749979

Comment: http://ideone.com/wmHPku

Comment: @kevmo314 Ok, that's odd. I don't know why it doesn't terminate for me.

Comment: Maybe I shouldn't use == to compare doubles ?

Comment: Generally that's true, but in your case you're exploiting the finite precision of a double, so using == is reasonable.

Comment: @kevmo314 That's wrong because the algorithm might reach a point where the compuatations don't change the values (because it's too small impact) but the condition still fails.

Comment: Your check is fine. Newton iteration won't converge to the square root for all inputs. Search for "Newton iteration converge" and read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why would anyone ever use that approach, when they could simply use the formulas for (2n^2) = 4n^2 and (n + 1)^2 = n^2 + 2n + 1, to populate each bit in the mantissa, and divide the exponent by two, multiplying the mantissa by two iff the the mod of the exponent with two equals 1?

Comment: Consider editing your question to change "you" to "You" and remove the words before it. That would make your answer nicer.

Answer (score 0):

To check if g and x/g are as close as the HW allow, look at the relative difference and compare
it with the epsilon for your floating point format. If it is within a small integer multiple of epsilon, you are OK.

Relative difference of x and y, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_change_and_difference

The epsilon for 32-bit IEEE floats is about 1.0e-7, as in one of the other answers here, but that answer used the absolute rather than the relative difference.

In practice, that means something like:

```
 Math.abs(g-x/g)/Math.max(Math.abs(g),Math.abs(x/g)) < 3.0e-7
```

Answer (score -1):

Never compare floating point values for equality. The result is not reliable.

Use a epsilon like so:

```
if(Math.abs(average-g) < 1e-7 || Math.abs(average-x/g) < 1e-7)
```

You can change the epsilon value to be whatever you need. Probably best is something related to the original x.